# issue with adding info bracket

Tags: xcode, swift

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This isn't working for me, I've tried adding ":" to my 'as' selector. Nothing seems to work. The error i keep getting is "'AnyObject?'is not convertible to 'UIImage'; did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast?" Any help will be much appreciated! THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

You should click on the error, click the "fix it" button, and let it show you how to add a force downcast.

You need to read the section in the Swift Language Reference on Optionals.